# "use of moved value" when the control flow won't allow it?

Tags: rust

This is a minimal reproduction of the code I'm struggling with:

```rust
// real code struct is not just a string, and is not cloneable
struct NotCloneable(String);

fn outer() -> Result<NotCloneable, String> {
    let obj = NotCloneable(String::from("Hello, world!"));
    might_fail().map_err(|_| {
        // real code closure might return one of several errors, including an
        // error containing non-cloneable fields from struct
        obj.0
    })?;
    // the ? means that if we got to here, the closure never executed
    // ... yet this won't compile because it claims the closure moved obj
    Ok(obj)
}

fn might_fail() -> Result<(), ()> {
    Err(())
}
```

It fails to compile with:

```
error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `obj`
  --> src/main.rs:16:8
   |
10 |     might_fail().map_err(|_| {
   |                          --- value partially moved into closure here
...
14 |         obj.0
   |         ----- variable partially moved due to use in closure
15 |     })?;
16 |     Ok(obj)
   |        ^^^ value used here after partial move
   |
   = note: partial move occurs because `obj.0` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: The problem is that `obj` is moved into the closure at the time the closure is _created_ whether it eventually gets executed or not. You might be able to do what you want with an explicit `match` instead of `map_err`.

Comment: Given the information in the question, [`match` most definitely does work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f0127c513b9f354f03a40b2ad9df7334) for this example.

Comment: My real code has a lot more logic in between the early-returned error and the eventual success result, so simply ending the function with a match statement isn't an option.  In fact there are about a dozen possible error conditions that need early return.  The '?' operator makes this easy; except in this case when it won't work :(

Answer (score 1):

After @Jmb's comment I also tried:

```rust
fn outer() -> Result<NotCloneable, String> {
    let obj = NotCloneable(String::from("Hello, world!"));
    match might_fail() {
        Ok(_) => Ok(()),
        Err(_) => Err(obj.0),
    }?;
    Ok(obj)
}
```

However, this fails to compile due the same error. What I did find is that if I explicitly early-return then it works:

```rust
fn outer() -> Result<NotCloneable, String> {
    let obj = NotCloneable(String::from("Hello, world!"));
    match might_fail() {
        Ok(_) => (),
        Err(_) => return Err(obj.0),
    };
    Ok(obj)
}
```

So it seems that whatever control flow analysis is happening is not smart enough to figure out that the capture is in an Err that is handled with an early return '?'.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that `Err(e)?` always returns; that's an implementation detail of how `Result` implements `Try`.